# how to open 'share picture via' popup menu on Adobe AIR for android?

Tags: android, air, adobe, popup, native

I made a little app on android where you can open (via the native file opener with filerefence.browse() it works beautifully) and save (directly to CameraRoll with addBitmapData also works perfectly) an image. Now i would like to share the saved image.

I would like to use the native android 'share picture via' popup. I found on a forum the native code for it ( [Android Share Via Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog) ).

Since we cannot execute native code for mobiles as i can read from the flash doc, is there a way to get this working at all?

Share via screenshot:
http://garr.me/wp-content/uploads/2009/12/sharevia.jpg

Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't an AIR API for this.  There is a way to combine AIR for Android apps with Native Android apps to access other APIs.  But it's a bit hacky and documentation on the subject is a bit lacking at the moment.  So for now your best options is probably to just write your own sharing UI and implementation.

Answer (score 0):

A while back a project called [Merapi](http://www.merapiproject.net/) was made, with the purpose of providing a bridge between AIR and Java on desktop apps. That might just provide you opportunity to get this running. Bear in mind though, that this is a guess, I have not tried this :)

Answer (score 0):

Build a Native Extension using the Air3.0 SDK.
An example of an air app that allows sharing can be found on this page:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/air/native-extensions-for-air.html.