# Share 3gp file to  youtube and facebook 

Tags: android

I am developing one application for android voice recording.The recoded voice is currently saved in .3gp formate.But I want to share this recorded 3gp file in to youtube and face bokk.

So Please any one help me how to share this 3gp file to facebook and youtube.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is vague (IMO). What programming language are you using? Java? It might be helpful to do a search for "YouTube API" or "Youtube API Android" (without quotes) before you ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to show how to share a file via an intent.  I have used ES File Explorer to share a file from my Android phone to Google Docs.  In fact, I just selected a 3gp video file and asked it to share it and one of the options that popped up was YouTube.  So yes, this can easily be done in Android with the proper intent (ACTION_SEND) and MIME Type.

[Android Share Via Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog)