# Share Android ImageView image

Tags: android

I want to make a functionality where I will have a button below ImageView. Upon clicking button, app will show all the apps with whom the image from ImageView can be shared like gamil/bluetooth/facebook and selecting one of the app, the image will be shared.

How can this is implemented ? Please help

Answer (score 2):

This is a blend of the answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3107527/android-save-view-to-jpg-or-png), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog). Save the view to a file using the first and then share it using the second.