# How to integrate google plus to Android application

Tags: android, android-dialog

I want to know how to integrate google plus in my app. Currently I am developing news application, in which I would like to have a news sharing option for things like facebook, twitter, gmail, and google plus. How can I achieve this functionality?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog

Comment: @jack Dsilva:Did u got the answer...? Me too searching the same..How to integrate Google Plus in android.If You know means..Please share the answer.

Comment: @Suraj: nope i didnt get,if i get answer obviously i will reply

Comment: Try This http://www.imellon.com/blog/2011/11/24/integrating-google-api-to-android/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sharing the Android way doesn't involve integrating services one by one. That would require you to update your app any time a new service launches that you might want to integrate with. Instead you use the [ACTION_SEND Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND).

This blog post gives a good intro to its use: http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/sharing-content-in-android-using-action_send-intent

When you implement sharing this way your users can share using any app they have installed on their device. If they install a new app that can accept sharing intents your app will immediately be able to integrate with it with no changes from you. The Google+ app accepts these sharing intents.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily share to Google+ with ShareCompat, you only need the support library for that.

http://googleplusplatform.blogspot.co.at/2012/05/sharing-rich-content-from-your-android.html