# Use share button (like in ICS gallary) instead of share dialoge (Intent.ACTION_SEND)

Tags: android, user-interface, share, image-gallery, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am trying to find a way to impelement a share button into my app (same like the one in the standard ICS gallary app, see picture link). 
http://betanews.com/2011/10/19/get-acquainted-with-the-newest-android-ice-cream-sandwich-slideshow/#11

Intent.ACTION_SEND only opens a dialoge to the select the sharing options. 
[Android Share Via Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog)

This works fine, but from design side, I find this drop down list to select a app much more convenient. 
Yet I cant figure out how to?
Does anybody have a good Idea how this button could be coded?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is implemented using a `ListPopupWindow`, which at the moment is only available on Android 4.0.

Comment: Ok, I checked the ListPopupWindow. This is capable to view a ListAdapter. But how to fill this Listadapter with all installed app, that can receive a certain kind of file / data?

Comment: @KarlKarlsom: Please ask separate StackOverflow questions for things that do not relate to a previous question. Comments are not a place to ask unrelated questions. That being said, you would use `PackageManager` and `queryIntentActivities()` to populate your list. The actual display-a-share-list-via-a-`ListPopupWindow` is implemented as [`ShareActionProvider`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ShareActionProvider.html), and since the Android 4.0 source code is available, you could always examine that to see exactly how they do it.

Answer (score 2):

This is implemented using ShareActionProvider available in SDK14+.

> ActionProvider class replaces an action item with a customized layout,
>   but it also takes control of all the item's behaviors. When you
>   declare an action provider for a menu item in the action bar, it not
>   only controls the appearance of the item in the action bar with a
>   custom layout, but also handles the default event for the menu item
>   when it appears in the overflow menu

Its quiet easy to implement, you can follow the official documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionProvider).