# Android button to share text from textview

Tags: android, textview

I need the share button to share the text in the textView in this way,I am a beginner in java and android

[image: explanation]

Comment: As you can see clearly, only 5 minutes of Googling gives you the result. So please try to solve issues using a search engine before involving people in solving them.

Answer (score 14):

on `Button Click`

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"Your score and Some extra text");
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "The title");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share..."));
```

Answer (score 2):

create a method which will be called on share button and add this lines in it

```
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Try this [link](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/) as well.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at how to use the Intent that launches the Share Via dialog.

See this post that has your answer : 
[Android Share Via Dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3553017/android-share-via-dialog)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete tutorial for this. http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-implement-a-share-intent/