# Share links with my app using "Share via" in Android

Tags: android

I'm trying to set my Android application so that it's available to share links from other apps such as Chrome running on Android.

I have set an Intent Filter on an activity so that my app displays in the "Share via" dialog.  That part works fine, but I'm not sure how to actually get the data into my "new post" dialog when it launches.

I read an existing StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3553102/262677) that suggests using this code:

```
Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
share.setType("text/plain");
share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm being sent!!");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Text"));
```

I have an existing method for creating posts that looks like this:

```
public void onNewPostMenuSelected(MenuItem item) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, CreatePostActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

Should I modify this existing method and, if so, how?  Or should I be doing something else?  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> I have set an Intent Filter on an activity so that my app displays in the "Share via" dialog. That part works fine, but I'm not sure how to actually get the data into my "new post" dialog when it launches.

If by "the data", you mean the text that was shared, call `getIntent()` on your activity and read the `EXTRA_TEXT` extra for that. In the case of browsers sharing URLs, `EXTRA_TEXT` should be the URL.